# how to execute a long shell with php ( by clicking button int this php page)

Tags: php

I have one shell which cost too much time to execute and I want to execute it by clicking button in web explorer.

but this php page always respone nothing because of the long excuting time?

how can I execute this shell and let the explorer know it is excuted succfully...

Comment: create a background job which sets a flag in a table which explorer can read using a javascript timer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the ideal use case for a job queue.

php job queues are covered in this question [PHP Advance Job Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672545/php-advance-job-queue)

I personally recommend [Gearman](http://www.gearman.org)