# Is Multithreading needed for a PHP Socket for GCM and MySQL Access

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, sockets, google-cloud-messaging

**tl;dr:** What is the best approach to keep a PHP Socket unblocked by MySQL Operations?

**Basic Goal:** Have a PHP+JAXL (XMPP)  Socket listen, read and write via a persistent TCP Connection to Googles CCS GCM Server. This was accomplished using this [CODE](https://gist.github.com/mstrengis/e9792c417735e6da2792).

- Now I need to **Process Data** (mostly MySQL) **without blocking** the Socket.

**What have i thought of:**

1: Have the Socket and the DB connection in two different PHP Threads. Communication could work via JobQueues. Implementations I found based on Geaman, Resque, BeanStalkD. These work however, mostly with a Master and Worker thread, so no bidirectional communication.

2: Implement a basic Queue as a global? Variable, Read Jobs from the DB thread, and put them back into another queue. (No idea whether smth lk this is possible)

3: Fork child processes like proposed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513112/asynchronous-processing-with-php-one-worker-per-job). I would then have to open a DB connection everytime I fork, which I thought I could avoid in some way. Also, how to call send() from child?.

**Hard Parts:**

1: Two-way communication required: DB Thread has to send results to Socket

2: <del>should work on Shared Hosting, e.g no Gearman, Redis installation.</del> 
also: no PHP skills

**What am I asking?:**

- What is needed to not block the Socket, and what not?
- Which approach is suited for my needs, especially when my DB-Thread has to assign jobs to the Socket ("send xy")?
- What am I understanding wrong here?

As you can see I lack the basic understanding, any guidance is very appreciated. Thanks alot.

Comment: Typically to communicate with GCM, you should have a separate process doing so. It is not recommanded to do that from PHP. If you do not want to write a push server, you can use a third-party service for push.

Comment: The Xmpp Socket is already running, written in PHP. I can receive and send Messages to GCM and handle ACKs. I linked the Code above, it works like:  
`$GCMSender = new GCMSender();
$GCMSender->processGCMs();`
I dont understand how I can process the messages "off-thread" and send back messages.

Answer (score 2):

All roads lead to Rome, but perhaps using [React PHP](http://reactphp.org/) is a solution for you.

It's an event-driven, non-blocking I/O library for PHP. It can handle your requirements, plus you don't have to dive into specifics to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

While its possible to write asynchronous queries with MySQLi, you can't just bundle it up with your network resources in the same *_select() call. However you could (in the same script) poll an asynchronous query. Just set a short timeout in socket_select() and in the same loop add a check for any completed mysql queries. Something like...

```
$wait=0;
while (true) {
    if (socket_select($netread, $netwrite, $netexcept
        , 0, $wait)) {
        // =...handle socket stuff
        $wait=200;
    }
    if (mysqli_poll($dbread, $dberror, $dbreject
         , 0, 0)) {
       //...handle mysql stuff
       $wait=0;
    }
}
```

(setting the wait to a non-zero value prevents the process eating all the CPU while doing nothing)
Alternatively you could use a SIGALARM to trigger the polling.

Answer (score 1):

Look this version of dnode for PHP:

https://github.com/bergie/dnode-php

useful to make process to comunicate